# how scipy.signal.step compute the time

Tags: python, scipy, signals

scipy.signal.step the documentation states that the simulation time is deducted if it is not specified.
How is this time determined if the function converges?

How come if it does not converge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy` is open source.  Currently the code resides on github at https://github.com/scipy/scipy.  The definition of `step` is currently in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/ltisys.py.  If you search that file for `def step(system`, you'll find the definition of the function.  Then you'll see that `step` calls the private function `_default_response_times(A, n)`, where `A` is the system matrix and `n` is the number of time samples to generate.  The complete code for this function is:

```
def _default_response_times(A, n):
    """Compute a reasonable set of time samples for the response time.
    This function is used by `impulse`, `impulse2`, `step` and `step2`
    to compute the response time when the `T` argument to the function
    is None.
    Parameters
    ----------
    A : array_like
        The system matrix, which is square.
    n : int
        The number of time samples to generate.
    Returns
    -------
    t : ndarray
        The 1-D array of length `n` of time samples at which the response
        is to be computed.
    """
    # Create a reasonable time interval.
    # TODO: This could use some more work.
    # For example, what is expected when the system is unstable?
    vals = linalg.eigvals(A)
    r = min(abs(real(vals)))
    if r == 0.0:
        r = 1.0
    tc = 1.0 / r
    t = linspace(0.0, 7 * tc, n)
    return t
```

You can see that the time interval is chosen using the minimum of the absolute values of the real parts of the eigenvalues.  Call this value *r*.  The end time is simply 7/*r* (unless *r* is 0, in which case the time is 7).